# Importing a SequenceClassification model for an NLP taks to Python

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, text-classification, transformer-model

I'm trying to use a SequenceClassification model for an NLP task and no matter which one I try if can be `RoBERTaConvForSequenceClassification`,`SqueezeBertForSequenceClassification`, `BARTForSequenceClassification` or `DistilBertForSequenceClassification` the import doesn't work. For example this line:

```py
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, XLNetForSequenceClassification"
```

gives me a mistake:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.xlnet.modeling_xlnet because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
name '_C' is not defined
```

But if I try to only do:

```py
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer
```

it works but not for the "SequenceClassification". I have the latest version of the `transformers` library and `PyTorch`.

Comment: Which OS, Python version and transformers/torch version are you using?

Comment: Please post the full error stacktrace.

Comment: Please share the full error stack. This `name _C` error is reported on Github and Pytorch and it seems to be related to the environment and the installation of pytorch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.